# Java: acces xml node atrributes value

Tags: java, xml, file, attributes

So, I have an XML file, and I want to read it and get the Client entities (identified by id & name) and to add them to a list and perform some operations on them, further. My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<clients>
<entity class="Domain.Client">
    <field name="id" type="java.lang.String" value="1"/>
    <field name="name" type="java.lang.String" value="Bia"/>
</entity>
<entity class="Domain.Client">
    <field name="id" type="java.lang.String" value="2"/>
    <field name="name" type="java.lang.String" value="Ana"/>
</entity>
```

The code for reading the XML looks like:

```
public List<Client> loadEntities() {
    List<Client> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlHelper docXml = new XmlHelper();       
    Document document = docXml.loadDocument(fileName);  // this function returns a Document
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList clients = root.getChildNodes();
    for (int i=0; i < clientElements.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        Node clientElement = clientElements.item(i);
            if (clientElement.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
            {
               // ignoring element due to wrong node type
               continue;
            }
            Element client = (Element) clientElement;
            String name = client.getElementsByTagName("name")
                                .item(i)
                                .getTextContent();

            int id = Integer.parseInt(client.getElementsByTagName("id")
                            .item(i)
                            .getTextContent());

            Client newClient = new Client(id, name);
            entities.add(newClient);

    }

    return entities;
}
```

but, I am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" ... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc for `getElementsByTagName` says:

*Returns a NodeList of all the Elements in document order with a given tag name and are contained in the document.*

You have **no** elements with tag name *name*, tag names are the names right after  `<`.
You have `<entity>` and `<field>` tag names.

To access the value of *name* **attribute** you can do something like this (untested code)

```
NodeList cNodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("field");

for(int i = 0; i < cNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
    Node cNode = cNodeList.item(i);
    Node dAttribute = cNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");
    String nameValue = dAttribute.getNodeValue()
    System.out.println(nameValue);
}
```

In general, post the complete stacktrace when you have an Exception.

**edit2**: I fixed the example code and now it should work as expected.

```
NodeList entityNodeList = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("entity");

for(int i = 0; i < entityNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
    String name = null;
    int id = 0;
    // Read all fields in the entity
    Element entity = (Element) entityNodeList.item(i);
    NodeList entityFields = entity.getElementsByTagName("field");
    for (int j = 0; j < entityFields.getLength(); ++j) {
        Node fieldNode = entityFields.item(j);
        Node dAttribute = fieldNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name");
        String attributeName = dAttribute.getNodeValue();
        System.out.println(attributeName);
        if (attributeName.equals("id")) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(fieldNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue());
        }
        if (attributeName.equals("name")) {
            name = fieldNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("name=" + name + ", id=" + id);
```

This outputs

```
id
name
name=Bia, id=1
id
name
name=Ana, id=2
```

Comment: Ok.. but how do I get the values of  the "id" and "name"..? Because, I tried something like you wrote:  "  Node dAttribute = clientElement.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(dAttribute.getNodeValue());
            String nameValue = dAttribute.getNodeValue();  ", but this won't work, because both "id" and "name" will have the value 1...

Comment: @Nelly I added a longer example to help you.

Comment: I saw it, thank you! But still, << fieldNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value")  >> , returns a node, not a String..

Comment: @ Alessandro I also tried: << name = dAttribute.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getTextContent(); >>, but I get the error:  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at utilities.XmlReader.loadEntities(XmlReader.java:50) [.....]
 "

Comment: @Nelly I wrote the code without running it and it had a couple of small mistakes. I corrected them and now it works. It grabs `id` and `name` for each `entity`.